# tmux: Cannot accept Keyboard Input

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tmux

I have the following simple code in a jupyter-notebook.

```
x=input()
print('input:{}'.format(x))
```

I use *runipy* to run this notebook in a tmux session. However, the session doesn't wait for my input to be entered and goes on and prints "print('input:{}'.format(x))". I used

```
tmux send-keys attach -t mysession "Hello" ENTER
```

But that only prints "Hello" n the session and it's like it doesn't put it in x. 
Can somebody please help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

using

```
jupyter nbconvert --to script [YOUR_NOTEBOOK].ipynb
```

I converted the notebook to a python script and ran it in a tmux session. It worked as expected! Thanks to my colleague for helping with this answer!